# IntelliJ Idea Selenium

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium

Доброго дня всем.
У меня вопрос, Господа.
Устанавливаю Idea на винду. И вот такой лог пишет.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и все. Не видит код как тест(

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась корректными настройками прокси)))